# Facebook graph search invalid app token

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I keep getting an invalid access token code 200 when searching the facebook graph with my valid app access token.  I know there are some July breaking changes coming up, but I don't think this has to do with that.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

says that App access tokens will be required for all search Graph API calls except Places and Pages. Search for application will no longer be supported.  I'm following the rules by searching public events with an app access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be obvious, but it's documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/:

> - Searches across page and place objects requires an app access token.
> - All other endpoints require a user access token.

You should use a **user access token** for search event.

If you think https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ is misleading, you should file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create

Comment: Ok thanks.  How then, do some websites search public events without requiring the user to log in?